# How to avoid css overlapping?

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar

I'm using `FullCalendar` with the resource library that you can see in my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JackIlpazzo/jc07k3dd/4/) 

How you can see the problem of the resource (first column, second column) is the overlapping. Seems infact if the resource have a long name go to overlap the near column and this is bad for me. What I want is cut the resource name if exceeds a certan lenght, anyway, the label must not overlap the next cell.
Issue image:

[image]

**Final result**

Something like: `First col | Second col`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to hide the overflow.

Your calendar's table header elements are overflowing into each other.

CSS:

```
#calendar tr th div.col-label{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This will make the overflowing text not draw instead of drawing on the next cells.

EDIT: Fixed this making the events disappear

EDIT 2: Fixed messing up the Date Label

Comment: Okay but how you can see now the day label is cut over the resource.

Comment: Fixed it! It looks perfect to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve your problem is by setting a `min-width` property on your columns in order to ensure that each one will have enough space available to store it's data. And then use `width:100%;` property on your labels. Maybe use some `padding` as well in order to make it look nice. Let me know if this helped :)